# PHP String Literal

Tags: php, string, concatenation, literals

I am trying to create a string in PHP that looks like this:

```
<xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways to create this and echo it out just like that, and have run into errors. So far, I have the variable $myvar hold the value TITLE, and added quotes around it using

`$myvar="\"". $myvar . "\"";` such that $myvar now looks like this `"TITLE"`

but trying to concatenate the rest gives me problems. It doesn't seem to like the <. I can echo that out as a variable if I put it in quotes, but if I try to concatenate it to any other string it disappears.

Any ideas how I can get that first string to be stored into a variable using the $myvar variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$foobar = 'TITLE';
echo '<xsl:sort select="' . $foobar. '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<xsl:sort select="' . $myvar . '"/>';
```